# How to animate using loading-bar

Tags: javascript, jquery, loading

Using the plugin **loading-bar** in  [loading.io](https://loading.io/progress)

I have included the js & css file.

**Heart Loader**:

```
<div style="width:300px; margin:auto"
   class="ldBar auto label-center"
   data-value="100"
   data-type="stroke"
   data-stroke="red"
   data-stroke-width="15"
   data-path="M90.5,23.2c0-12.5-10.2-22.7-22.7-22.7 c-13.6,0-20.9,8.6-22.3,13.8C44.3,8.9, 35.1,0.5,23.2,0.5C10.7,0.5,0.5,10.7, 0.5,23.2c0,22.2,36.5,45.3,45,55.9 C53.5,67.3,90.5,46.3,90.5,23.2z">
</div>
```

Actual code result:

[image]

How to animate this, from **0 -> 100%**

Need some help.
Thanks.

Comment: What's the question? what have you tried? what didn't work? how does it not work? Where do you need help? At the moment youre basically asking *"guys, can you write this for me?"*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should set `data-value="0"` to the html element and set and `id` attribute like `<div id="myHeart"` so you can query more easy the element

then in your js code where you initialize the ldbar

like this `var bar1 = new ldBar("#myHeart");`

you get the bar1 variable and say

`bar1.set(100)`

and it will automatically animate

Comment: i missed that on docu :(
@gijoe Thank you!